# update df column value based on another df python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df `qty` and df `item_info`, I was trying to fill the NaN fields in `qty['item']` where : (i will quote SQL here)

`qty.ccy = item_info.ccy and qty.seller =  item_info.seller`
where the tuple (ccy,seller) are unique identifier on both DFs.

```
DF qty
|  id | qty  |   item   | ccy | seller |
+-----+------+----------+-----+--------+
| 001 |  700 | CB04 box | USD | A1     |
| 002 |  500 | NaN      | AUS | A1     |
| 003 | 1500 | AB01 box | USD | B1     |



DF item_info
| sid | seller | ccy |   item   |
+-----+--------+-----+----------+
| AA1 | A1     | USD | CB04 box |
| AA2 | A2     | USD | CB01 Box |
| AA3 | A1     | AUS | AB01 box |
```

and the updated DF `qty` will look like this

```
DF qty
|  id | qty  |   item   | ccy | seller |
+-----+------+----------+-----+--------+
| 001 |  700 | CB04 box | USD | A1     |
| 002 |  500 | AB01 box | AUS | A1     |
| 003 | 1500 | AB01 box | USD | B1     |
```

Comment: If i get it right than you just have to iterate through the qty Data frame and check if there is any NaN value in qty['item'] series if it is than pickup the qty['ccy'] and qty['seller'] values from the same index and search those values in the item_info dataframe if these are unique then you will get a single row and then you can get the item_info['item'] value and can replace that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy might be to merge the two tables on the columns you need to match and then use fillna.

```
values = qty.merge(item_info, on=["ccy", "seller"], 
             how="left", suffixes=("_qty", "_info"))["item_info"]
qty["item"] = qty["item"].fillna(value=values)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfg_item_info = item_info.groupby(["ccy", "seller"])
def fillna(x):
    if np.isnan(x["C"]):
        return (dfg_item_info
               .get_group((x["ccy"], x["seller"]))["item"]
               .values[0])
    else:
        return x["item"]

qty["item] = qty["item"].apply(fillna, axis=1)
```